# How to re-run Ubuntu Welcome app?

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I just installed U18 in VirtualBox 6, and unfortunately I inserted the Guest Additions CD before the Welcome app ran, and ended up accidentally quitting the Welcome app when it did show up.  I can't find it in the "Show Applications" screen, so how can I re-run it?

Comment: You're right about the other question, but for some reason clicking the "That solved my problem!" is not responding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* this is what you're looking for: (run this in the terminal)

```
/usr/lib/gnome-initial-setup/gnome-initial-setup --existing-user
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick and correct reply!  U18 actually ran it on the next boot as it must have realised I had not completed it.